# Creating SAML Response throws an exception

Tags: c#, saml

```
samlResponse = ComponentPro.Saml2.Response.Create(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

this line throws an exception "The SAML response signature failed to verify."

The same code works just fine on a different site on the same server. The only difference between the sites is that this site has SSL certificate installed.

Kind of new to this SSO thing so a detailed explanation is appreciated (if possible),

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with component you're using - but I'm fairly experienced with SAML. Your remote party is signing the xml (SAML response) with their private certificate. You than validate with their public certificate you've stored locally, if signature matches (so the message wasn't tampered with). This error is caused by 1) message was tampered with 2) you're using wrong certificate to validate the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was using wrong certificate.  They had the same file names so I grabbed the wrong one.